# Struct to JSON with two objects

Tags: go

I made a struct:

```
var gateSettings struct {
Publisher struct {
    Status   string `json:"status"`
    Gateways []struct {
        AppTest1 struct {
            PlacementID int `json:"placementId"`
        } `json:"apptest1,omitempty"`
        AppTest2 struct {
            NetworkID int `json:"networkId"`
            SiteID    int `json:"siteId"`
        } `json:"apptest2,omitempty"`
    } `json:"gateways"`
} `json:"publisher"`
```

}

This is the struct for my json file:

```
{
"publisher": {
    "status": "enabled",
    "gateways": [
        {
            "apptest1": {
                "placementId": 109
            }
        },
        {
            "apptest2": {
                "networkId": 12,
                "siteId": 221
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I decode this JSON in my go script:

```
jsonParser := json.NewDecoder(configFile)
err = jsonParser.Decode(&gateSettings)
if err != nil {
    return nil, []error{&errortypes.BadServerResponse{
        Message: fmt.Sprintf("Unable to decode json"),
    }}
}
```

The problem is when I print the gateSettings.Publisher.Gateways, I got a strange thing, I retrieve two objects of two objects, the first one with the first object with value and second at 0 ... it is difficult to explain, so look example:

```
        fmt.Println(gateSettings.Publisher.Gateways)
```

OUTPUT =

[{{109} {0 0 0 0}} {{0} {12 221}}]

I hope you understand, I would like to retrieve directly this:

```
[{{109} {12 221}}]
```

Comment: if you want something to be not there when empty, use pointer so it can be nil.

Comment: in terms of printing. go will always print all the fields.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the problem is that every part of my struct is populate, nothing is null or at 0. (See my json in my post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, just need to change struct like this :

```
var gateSettings struct {
Publisher struct {
    Status   string `json:"status"`
    Gateways struct {
        AppTest1 struct {
            PlacementID int `json:"placementId"`
        } `json:"apptest1,omitempty"`
        AppTest2 struct {
            NetworkID int `json:"networkId"`
            SiteID    int `json:"siteId"`
        } `json:"apptest2,omitempty"`
    } `json:"gateways"`
} `json:"publisher"`
```

and json like this :

```
{
"publisher": {
    "status": "enabled",
    "gateways": {
        
            "apptest1": {
                "placementId": 109
            }
        ,
        
            "apptest2": {
                "networkId": 12,
                "siteId": 221
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go is printing the default zero values for the struct part that you did not populate. Gateways needs to be an array of pointers tagged as omitempty to get an output like what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the problem is that every part of my struct is populate, nothing is null or at 0. (See my json in my post)